# Data from past 30 days works, but the previous 30 days does not?

Tags: sql-server

Getting the last 30 days in SQL is pretty simple

```
SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable] 
WHERE [CreatedDate] >= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE()) 
and [CreatedDate] <= getdate()
```

But I'm now trying to get the previous 30 days

```
SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable] 
WHERE [CreatedDate] >= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE()) 
and [CreatedDate] <= DATEADD(day,-60,GETDATE())
```

This does not work. To me, I don't see how the last 30 days can work, but the previous 30 days cannot? I must be doing something silly here, could anybody shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How can a date be **greater than** 30 days ago and be **less than** 60 days ago? Unless you can think of a number that is less than 30 and more than 60? :)

Comment: @Larnu, ok, that made me giggle :D

Answer (score 1):

YOu need to reverse the date range:

```
SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable] 
WHERE [CreatedDate] >= DATEADD(day,-60,GETDATE()) 
and [CreatedDate] <= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE());
```

Comment: The time portion of GETDATE() should be considered as well

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the comparison

```
SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable] 
WHERE [CreatedDate] >= DATEADD(day,-60,GETDATE()) and 
[CreatedDate] <= DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some alternate approaches to the existing answers:

```
/* this is probably my favorite of the options, very little code and would be easy to parameterize the day range */
SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable] 
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, cast([CreatedDate] as date), cast(GETDATE() as date)) BETWEEN 30 and 60

/* casting as date will remove the need to worry about time of day */
SELECT * FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable] 
WHERE cast([CreatedDate] as date) between dateadd(day, -60, cast(getdate() as date))
                                      and dateadd(day, -30, cast(getdate() as date))
```

Comment: I really like the first approach. Thanks for sharing